# SQL Using Cross Apply makes the query to run very slow

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, cross-apply

The below query takes 35sec to complete, so the front end app throws 'Timeout expired' error, I fixed by increasing CommandTimeOut, but my reviewer didn't accept the fix ,because fix has to be done in sql query.

Below is My sql query

```
select * from SamplesPartners as sp WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) WHERE (EXISTS
(
    SELECT      *
    FROM        SamplesPartners  AS sp2
    CROSS APPLY SE_GetCurrentParentContainersForItem(sp2.samplePartnerSqlId, sp2.samplePartnerIncId, 2, 293) AS CC
    JOIN        dbo.Containers   AS C ON    C.containerSqlId = CC.containerSqlId
                                        AND C.containerIncId = CC.containerIncId
                                        AND C.isDeleted      = 0x0
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.Shipments    AS S ON    S.containerSqlId = C.containerSqlId
                                        AND S.containerIncId = C.containerIncId
                                        AND S.isDeleted      = 0x0
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.Destinations AS D ON    D.containerSqlId = C.containerSqlId
                                        AND D.containerIncId = C.containerIncId
                                        AND D.isDeleted      = 0x0
    WHERE       sp2.samplePartnerSqlId = sp.samplePartnerSqlId
    AND         sp2.samplePartnerIncId = sp.samplePartnerIncId
    AND         (
                    C.containerCode   LIKE '%test%'
                OR  C.containerName   LIKE '%test%'
                OR  S.trackingNumber  LIKE '%test%'
                OR  D.destinationName LIKE '%test%'
                )   
    AND         sp2.isDeleted = 0x0
)) and isDeleted=0
```

Below is the Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SE_GetCurrentParentContainersForItem]
(
    @itemSqlId          SMALLINT,
    @itemIncId          INT,
    @itemMetaTableSqlId SMALLINT,
    @itemMetaTableIncId INT
)
RETURNS TABLE

AS

RETURN
WITH      ContainersMetaTable AS (
           -- Returns only 1 record.
           SELECT    metaTableSqlId,metaTableIncId FROM dbo.MetaTables WHERE metaTableName = 'Containers'),
          ContainerSubtree AS (
           -- Anchor member.
           SELECT    containerSqlId,containerIncId,0 AS lvl
           FROM      dbo.ContainersContents
           WHERE     contentSqlId          = @itemSqlId
             AND     contentIncId          = @itemIncId
             AND     contentMetaTableSqlId = @itemMetaTableSqlId
             AND     contentMetaTableIncId = @itemMetaTableIncId
             AND     isDeleted             = 0

           UNION ALL

           -- Recursive member.
           SELECT    cc.containerSqlId,
                     cc.containerIncId,
                     sub.lvl + 1        AS lvl
           FROM      ContainersMetaTable    AS cmt,
                     dbo.ContainersContents AS cc
           JOIN      ContainerSubtree       AS sub ON  cc.contentSqlId = sub.containerSqlId
                                                   AND cc.contentIncId = sub.containerIncId
                                                   AND cc.isDeleted    = 0
           WHERE     cc.contentMetaTableSqlId = cmt.metaTableSqlId
             AND     cc.contentMetaTableIncId = cmt.metaTableIncId             
          )
SELECT    containerSqlId,
          containerIncId,
          lvl
FROM      ContainerSubtree
```

I couldn't find out the place where I can change and improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I change your query to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SamplesPartners AS sp WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) 
WHERE (EXISTS (
    SELECT      1
    FROM        SamplesPartners  AS sp2
    CROSS APPLY SE_GetCurrentParentContainersForItem(sp2.samplePartnerSqlId, sp2.samplePartnerIncId, 2, 293) AS CC
    JOIN        dbo.Containers   AS C ON    C.containerSqlId = CC.containerSqlId
                                        AND C.containerIncId = CC.containerIncId
                                        AND C.isDeleted      = 0
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.Shipments    AS S ON    S.containerSqlId = C.containerSqlId
                                        AND S.containerIncId = C.containerIncId
                                        AND S.isDeleted      = 0
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.Destinations AS D ON    D.containerSqlId = C.containerSqlId
                                        AND D.containerIncId = C.containerIncId
                                        AND D.isDeleted      = 0
    WHERE       sp2.samplePartnerSqlId = sp.samplePartnerSqlId
    AND         sp2.samplePartnerIncId = sp.samplePartnerIncId
    AND         (C.containerCode + ':' + C.containerName + ':' + S.trackingNumber + ':' + D.destinationName) LIKE '%test%'
    AND         sp2.isDeleted = 0
    ))
```

I change this:

- Removing `OR` operator and merge all `LIKE` operators to reduce seeking over your data.
- Using `1` as one field instead of `*` as many field to reduce using of memory.
- I change `isDeleted = 0x0` to `isDeleted = 0` to reduce type conversion for it as I think its type is not `varbinary` as you also use it in your table-value function.
- I remove last `AND isDeleted = 0` because you are checking it inside the `EXISTS` part.

Comment: Removing 'OR' operator and merge all 'LIKE' operators gives "zero" results. Even when I implement other two improvements the total performance time remains same.

Comment: @Selva *Removing 'OR' operator and merge all 'LIKE' operators* will give you same result, second option make a better performance on servers with a limitation of memory and third that I ask about type of `isDeleted` field is it exactly `varbinary`?

Comment: Removing 'OR' operator and merge all 'LIKE' operators giving zero results, believe me:) and "isDeleted" type is "bit". and you were mentioning about replacing Table value function, could you please elaborate?